# Highcharts - How to add / display label's name data from count() query result

Tags: javascript, mysql, highcharts

We want ask you all for our problem for displaying the label's name from result of count()'s query. We have figured out for 2 day and we did not found the solution.

First, this is the database

[image: Database's picture, focus on 'f5' column to displaying on highcharts]

Secondly, we produced query result (this is our Model's Class)

```
public function ambilDataLamaWaktuTunggu(){
  // select f5, count(*) from tracer_study as pilihanF5 GROUP BY f5 
  $this->db->select("f5, count(id_tracer_study) as'pilihanF5'");
  $this->db->from('tracer_study');
  $this->db->group_by('f5');
  $result = $this->db->get()->result();
  return $result;
}
```

The Result of this query is

[image: Result count's query]

Thirdly, this is View (this is snap of javascript's code) to show Pie Chart (We use, highcharts)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
  foreach ($num as $row){
    $data[] = $row->pilihanF5;
    $dataNama[] = $row->f5;
  }
?>

$('.grafik').highcharts({
  chart:{
    type: 'pie',
    marginTop: 50,
    renderTo: 'container'
  },
  credits:{
    enabled:false
  },
  tooltip:{
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y} Orang</b>'
  },
  title:{
    text: 'Lama Waktu Tunggu untuk Pekerjaan Pertama'
  },
  subtitle:{
    text: 'Alumni Lulusan 2015-2016'
  },
  xAxis:{
    categories:['Waktu Tunggu xAxis'],
    labels:{
      style:{
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
    }
  },
  legend:{
    labelFormatter: function(){
      if(this.name == 'Langsung Bekerja')
        return this.name + ': 1 Orang';
      else if (this.name == '1 Bulan') {
        return this.name + ': 2 Orang';
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions:{
    pie:{
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels:{
        enabled:true
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
  series:[{
    'name':'Jumlah ',
    'data':[
       <?php echo join( $data, ',')?>
    ]
  }]
});
```

And The End of, what we ask. This is screen shoot of the webpage.
[image: screen shoot of diagram]

Question :
We want to add label's name with the value from database. Not only show 'Slice'. We want display the name of the data from database.
Please for any solution or suggestion for you all.

I'm sorry, for this newbie question. 
Thank you very much for your atention and solution.

Comment: Specify a name for each point in the pie - by default the data labels have text which are the points' names - http://jsfiddle.net/7w889wtv/

Comment: Thank you for your response @morganfree , but we did not want echo manual or specific name. We want dynamic label's name from query result data which we made. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: So this is a question regarding your back end - how to retrieve a proper data from your db? If so, I suggest to trim the front end part of that question and ask a new question. If you have retrieved you data properly from db, then you have to place it in the config object - by echoing it - either by points' names or [dataLabels.format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.dataLabels.format)

Comment: Thank you @morganfree , I had figured out the way what we want. So many thanks for your suggestions, I've appreciate that. Nice to meet you, see you again later.